# Do I need to specify nonce in token transfer code?

Tags: erc-20

I am using ethers.js to transfer erc20 token. How do I put nonce in transfer? Nonce can be any number?

Comment: "Nonce can be any number?" - No, it has to be equal to the number of transaction executed with your account so far, which you can get, for example, using web3.js function `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account)`. For the other two questions, please open the offiial documentation of ethers.js and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Nonce is the number of transactions associated with the address you're using - accounts start at 0, contracts start at 1.

Comment: Can I give the nonce freely?

Comment: No, as I said in my anser, it's the amount of transactions associated with your account, i.e. you cannot send a trx with nonce 3 if you haven't already sent transactions with nonces 0,1, and 2.